# Obtaining coordinate data by identifying coordinate picture with python

Tags: python, coordinates

I want get the yellow line's coordinate datas (eg :(49,1500),(49.1,1500)....) in the coordinate picture, by which datas I can draw a new coordinate picture.
How do I  identify the coordinate picture and get this datas in Python?

[coordinate picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZLsf.png)

Comment: Where does the coordinate picture comes from? You have no access to the data but only this picture?

Comment: yeah,just  these pictures.